# JavaScript not firing in .ASCX page

Tags: sitecore, ascx

I know I am new to the .net world, so there are limitations to what I know and understand. I am using Sitecore, and Sitecore generates the .aspx pages behind the scenes, so I have no access to the source, what I do have access to is the .ascx which is the sublayout ... so i tried to put some javascript onto the layout ... and I read that I am allowed to this with  tags, but when I run the program now, it is not firing. Anything I am missing, please advise. Thank you for your assistance.

```
 <!-- Custom Feedback Code -->
<script type="text/javascript">


    function showModal() {

        var url = document.URL;

        var popUp = 'http://local.meau.com/components/supportcenter/feedback.aspx?value=';
        var site = popUp + url;
        var runpopUp = 50;
        if (runpopUp >= Math.random() * 100) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.fancybox({
                    'width': 500,
                    'height': '55%',
                    'autoScale': false,
                    'transitionIn': 'none',
                    'transitionOut': 'none',
                    'type': 'iframe',
                    'href': site,
                    'showCloseButton': false,
                    'title': 'We Request your Feedback'

                });

            });
        }

    }


</script>
<!-- End of Custom Feedback Code -->
```

Comment: From what I see you define `showModal` function but you never execute it. Try to add `showModal();` before the closing `</script>` tag.

Comment: Thank you Maras, i though something like that was the issue, but I added the showModal() and it still isn't firing. I will keep trying different things. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to start by removing (commenting out) the randomization logic - to make sure that your code is working deterministically first. Next, what is done in your code - the anonymous function is added as `$(document).ready` event handler inside `showModal` function. Unless you call `showModal` before `$(document).ready` fires, your handler will never be executed. Therefore, @Maras's suggestion should work, assuming, of course, that `jquery` javascript is loaded into the page.

Comment: thank you, that did work. Now, i just need to figure out how to put that randomized logic back in. But, thank you for your assistance.